# Comparing different and unequal lists in R to find the most similar candidates

Tags: r, list, keyword, similarity

I’m trying to do some basic keyword matching in R, but I can’t quite figure it out given different and unequal lists.
Imagine that I have descriptions of five different bird species (birds), and four specimens (specimens) that have a subset of these descriptors.

```
birds <- list(
  bird_1 = c("scolopacidae", "wet", "omnivore", "large", "siberia"),
  bird_2 = c("woodland", "scolopacidae", "medium", "siberia", "omnivore"),
  bird_3 = c("wet", "charadriidae", "insectivore", "medium", "tasmania"),
  bird_4 = c("siberia", "apodidae", "insectivore", "arial", "medium"),
  bird_5 = c("meropidae", "wet forest", "omnivore", "small", "australia")
)

specimens <- list(
  specimen_1 = c("nectarivore", "scolopacidae", "alaska"),
  specimen_2 = c("alaska", "scolopacidae", "woodland", "omnivore"),
  specimen_3 = c("china", "sylviidae", "south australia"),
  specimen_4 = c("wet forest", "small", "tasmania", "insectivore", "charadriidae")
)
```

[image: example]

I’m trying to compare each specimen to each bird and count up the number of descriptors that they share like this.

Ultimately, for each specimen, I’d like to return a rank ordering of the possible birds that it matches from the most corresponding descriptors to the least. For example: specimen_4 = bird_3, bird_5, bird_4, bird_1, bird_2

Can anyone point me in the right direction? I'd really appreciate your help.

Answer (score 0):

You may take help of `outer` -

```
calculate <- function(x, y) sum(x %in% y)
outer(birds, specimens, Vectorize(calculate))

#       specimen_1 specimen_2 specimen_3 specimen_4
#bird_1          1          2          0          0
#bird_2          1          3          0          0
#bird_3          0          0          0          3
#bird_4          0          0          0          1
#bird_5          0          1          0          2
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is one possible way to solve your problem:

```
out = sapply(specimens, function(s) sapply(birds, function(b) length(intersect(s, b))))

#        specimen_1 specimen_2 specimen_3 specimen_4
# bird_1          1          2          0          0
# bird_2          1          3          0          0
# bird_3          0          0          0          3
# bird_4          0          0          0          1
# bird_5          0          1          0          2


ranks <- sapply(colnames(out), function(s) names(sort(out[,s], TRUE)))

#    specimen_1 specimen_2 specimen_3 specimen_4
# [1,]  "bird_1"   "bird_2"   "bird_1"   "bird_3"  
# [2,]  "bird_2"   "bird_1"   "bird_2"   "bird_5"  
# [3,]  "bird_3"   "bird_5"   "bird_3"   "bird_4"  
# [4,]  "bird_4"   "bird_3"   "bird_4"   "bird_1"  
# [5,]  "bird_5"   "bird_4"   "bird_5"   "bird_2"
```